# more sophisticated adding value into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I just wonder, is there an elegant way to add element in an array, in situation where I don't know beforehand, whether I want to create new index or use existing one?

```
$array[$k] = $foo; // this overwrites existing index, never creates one
$array[] = $foo; // this always creates new one, never overwrites
array_push(...); // always creates new index  
$array[null] = $foo // sadly, null is casted to empty string
```

It would be nice to do something like this:

```
if($key === null) $array[] = $foo;  
else $array[$key] = $foo;
```

but fit it in one expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array[!isset($key) || $key === null? count($array) : $key ] = $foo;
```

update: improved with `isset()`

Comment: Ah, true, ternary operator is probably as elegant as it can get. Thanx.

Comment: As I am thinking about it now, it doesn't really do what I want. In case index with same number as size of array already exists, it would overwrite it. Gosh, damn php.

Answer (score -1):

This is what `array_key_exists()` is for!

```
if(array_key_exists($key, $array))
    $array[$key] = $value;
else
    $array[] = $value;
```